# Code Igniter add css

Tags: javascript, css, codeigniter

Although this question was on this forum, i'd like to ask you again. How to attach css and js files properly in CI (Code Igniter framework)

here is my code:

views/header -   `<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/example.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">`

autoload.php - `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

But css doesn't work. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

put your assets folder with applications, system, assets

not in application and simple load the url helper class in controller where you call the header view part something like

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->view('header');
```

and simply use something like this in your header file..
because $this->base_url() return the / folder..

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->base_url();?>/assets/javascript/jquery.js"></scirpt>
```

Changing the folder structure because access within the application folder is just for the core part that i know..

Answer (score 0):

My way is to create a folder called assets and the put them your css and js files.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url(); ?>asset/js/your_script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url(); ?>asset/css/your_style.css"></script>
```

It is important to use base_url instead of full domain name.
Then moving your app to the new server is easy.